# Use the phone's power button to open the app in the flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am writing an application with a flutter and I want to open the application for the person who has the application by pressing the power button three times. How can I do that?

Comment: Interesting!!! Did you see this in any of the app. IMO, this is not doable...

Comment: Definitely can't do this on iOS and I would be very surprised if you could do it on Android

Comment: On iOS , this action is in accessibility and you can only set it to specific behaviour. I